# Lazy load hidden content with Boostrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, lazy-loading

How can I lazy load the entire content included in the hidden-xs hidden-sm div to prevent the images and links from loading on a mobile device?

I need to lazy load the entire content not just images. Imagine this is for a large menu with many hidden categories in desktop that need not display in mobile.

```
<div class="row hidden-xs hidden-sm"> 
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x100">
    <a herf="/desktop-account/">Login</a>
  </div>
</div>  

<div class="row hidden-md hidden-lg"> 
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100">
    <a herf="/mobile-account/">Login</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't really specific to Bootstrap. Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You can load the content via `ajax`. Therefore you need a `div` as container and another page with the content you want to load.

This would be your container on the first page. The content is accessible via, lets say, http://link/to/content

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Loading the content can easily be done with `jquery`.

```
$('document').on('ready', function() {

  if (!...) { // check for mobile device
    $('#container').load('http://link/to/content.html')
  }
}
```